# Function-like C macro without parentheses

Tags: c, debugging, macros

I have encountered the following debug macro in an embedded device codebase:

```
extern void DebugPrint(uint8_t *s);

#define DEBUG_MSG(x)   do { PRINT_CURRENT_TIME; \
                            DebugPrint x ; } while(0)
```

Since there are no parentheses around `x` in the macro body (at the `DebugPrint x` part), all calls to this macro (all over the codebase) add another set of parentheses around strings:

```
DEBUG_MSG(("some debug text"));
```

Is there any reason to do this? Does it simplify optimizing away these calls in release builds, or something like that? Or is it just plain nonsense?

I thought perhaps there would be additional overloads of `DebugPrint` with more arguments, but there are none.

Comment: This is mere speculation, but it could be a trick to be able to weasel some additional code in there: `DEBUG_MSG(("foo"); callBarFunc());`

Comment: @WanderNauta: I hope not, that's pure evil. :-) Especially since you can just add the function call *after* the macro call in this case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a theory:

The preprocessor parses the arguments of a macro expansion in a way that mimics the compiler's expression parsing. In particular it parses terms in parentheses as a single argument.

So the `DEBUG_MSG` author's intention might have been to enforce the use of parentheses.

This might make sense when the `DebugPrint` print function would actually be a `printf` style *variadic* function. You could call the function with a single string literal or with a variable number of arguments:

```
DEBUG_MSG(("reached this point in code"));

DEBUG_MSG(("value of x = %i", x));
```

But this is pure speculation. Can't you just ask the author?

Comment: +1 Thanks, that would make some sense - although it's weird one would choose this approach over [`__VA_ARGS__`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro), which I find a lot more explicit about its intent.

Comment: I totally agree, yet I think there was some problem with `__VA_ARGS__` and single argument expansions. Some gnu extension was needed to make this work properly. Not sure about that, it's been a while :)

Comment: [Here are the details.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) If the code was for some embedded device, the compiler might have been lacking support for this extension.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that no. Macros are replaced by the compiler, so they have nothing to do with execution speeds. This:

```
#define MACRO(x) do_something(x)
MACRO("test");
```

Is no different than this

```
#define MACRO(x) do_something x
MACRO(("test"));
```

Since the compiler will replace them both with the same output:

```
do_something("test");
```

which will then compile to produce the same object code.

Comment: I understand that, I wanted to see if someone might know a practical reason  why someone would choose the latter version (which requires more typing, and will fail if you omit inner parenthesis.